# how to group based on id and a condition like date comparison between documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, group

In the following collection:

```
[
  {
    "p_id": "102",
    "e_date": ISODate("2017-04-01T00:00:00.000+00:00"),
    "h_val": 4,
    
  },
  {
    "p_id": "102",
    "e_date": ISODate("2005-04-01T00:00:00.000+00:00"),
    "h_val": 5,
    
  },
  {
    "p_id": "102",
    "e_date1": ISODate("2017-05-01T00:00:00.000+00:00"),
    "s_val": 87,
    "d_val": 58
  },
  {
    "p_id": "102",
    "e_date1": ISODate("2016-09-01T00:00:00.000+00:00"),
    "s_val": 81,
    "d_val": 62
  },
  {
    "p_id": "102",
    "e_date1": ISODate("2010-09-01T00:00:00.000+00:00"),
    "s_val": 81,
    "d_val": 62
  },
  {
    "p_id": "101",
    "e_date": ISODate("2016-04-01T00:00:00.000+00:00"),
    "h_val": 5,
    
  },
  {
    "p_id": "101",
    "e_date1": ISODate("2015-05-01T00:00:00.000+00:00"),
    "s_val": 87,
    "d_val": 58
  },
  
]
```

I want to compare the dates within each p_id and group those documents with e_date1 < e_date only.

I have tried the group aggregation and used a condition to find the e_date1 less than e_date but it just pushes either documents containing e_date1 or e-date. it does not bring up the corresponding documents. I am not sure if group would be the right solution for this.

```
{
"_id": {
  "pid": "$p_id",
  "date": {
    "$cond": [
      { "$lt": [ "$e_date1", "$e_date" ] },
      "edate1<edate",
      "edate<edate1",
    ]
  }
},
"records": {"$push": "$$ROOT"},
"count": { "$sum": 1 },
  }
```

Comment: I think you will want to move that check to a $match stage (with $expr) before the $group in order to filter the documents down to only the ones that you are interested in

Comment: I have tried that as well but it does not pair the results. It just gets either the documents containing e_date1 or e_date. Here are the aggregate stages:                                         db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$match": {$expr: {$lte: ["$e_date","$e_date_1"]}}},
  {"$group": {"_id": "$p_id","actions": {"$push": "$$ROOT"},"total": {"$sum": 1}}}
])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `e_date1` and `e_date` are not on the same document, one option is to group and only then filter (during the grouping you still don't know what is the `e_date` value to compare to):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$group: {
      _id: "$p_id",
      e_date: {$first: "$e_date"},
      records: {$push: "$$ROOT"}
  }},
  {$project: {
      p_id: "$_id", _id: 0, e_date:1, 
      records: {$filter: {
          input: "$records",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {$gt: ["$$this.e_date1", null]},
              {$lt: ["$$this.e_date1", "$e_date"]}
            ]
          }
      }}
  }},
  {$addFields: {count: {$size: "$records"}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZpJfGfscOOe)

If you have many documents that should be filtered out and you don't want to group them all into one giant document, you can use the `$setWindowFields` before continuing along the guidelines of @user20042973.

Comment: Great solution. Any idea, how to add the related e_date fields to the results?

Comment: Updated to add the `e_date` in the result